# Regular Expression in excel VBA

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm trying to use regex in excel VBA to match a pattern within all cells in a column range, and remove the matched patterns to a new column range.

E.g.

1. Happy Day Care Club (1124734)
2. French Pattiserie (8985D)
3. The King's Pantry (G6666642742D)
4. Big Shoe (China) Ltd (ZZ454)

Essentially I want to remove the last bracketed portion of each string and transpose this part (without the brackets) into a different column range.

The regex I have so far is "(([^)]+))\z" (which I don't know if this is actually correct), and embedded within this VBA:

```
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim Myrange As Range

Sheets("Sheet 1").Activate
Range("FF65536").End(xlUp).Select
LastCell = ActiveCell.Address

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("FF2:" & LastCell)

For Each C In Myrange
    strPattern = "(\(([^\)]+)\)\z)"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = C.Value
        strReplace = "$1"

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            Range("FF2").Select = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$1")
            Range("DX2").Select = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$2")
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I'm a newbie so please forgive glaringly obvious mistakes.

Many thanks,

Comment: If the pattern is the same, as in the bracketed portion is always at the end you could use the split function. It would use a lot less code to get the same thing.

Comment: You can also use this `\s*(\((.*?)\))$` regex if there are `(` or `)` inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

No your regex pattern isn't correct. You should test your pattern separately as regex is its own mini-language. Try this pattern ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iF4xA4/1)):

```
\((.+)\)$
```

About the `gm` options: `g` means `Global`, `m` means `Multiline`, both of which are set to `True` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-RegEx method:

```
Dim Myrange As Range

Sheets("Sheet 1").Activate

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("FF2:FF" & Cells(Rows.Count, "FF").End(xlUp).Row)
With Myrange
    .Offset(, -43).Value = .Worksheet.Evaluate("INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(" & .Address & _
                                            ",""("",REPT("" "",500)),500)),"")"",""""),)")
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would resort to RegEx as a last resort...

Here is a snippet using string functions:

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim s As String
For iRow = 1 To UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Debug.Print Cells(iRow, 1).Value
    s = Cells(iRow, 1).Value
    s = Trim(Left(s, InStrRev(s, "(") - 1))
    Debug.Print s
Next
```

The relevant line being `Trim(Left(s, InStrRev(s, "(") - 1))`. You would need QA check to deal with data w/o proper format.